# Retrive children of current item using GlassMapper

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

if we already have current item in a serivce/repository then how we can get children of that item using glass ? I don't see mvcContext or SitecoreService has GetChildren related method

Answer (score 0):

Glass Mapper has `IItemFactory` which you can inject to your code with dependency injection.

And then you can use

```
_itemFactory.SelectChildren<ChildType>(parentObject)
_itemFactory.SelectChildren<ChildType>(parentItem.ID.ToGuid())
```

You should be able to get children also using

```
parentObject.Children<ChildType>()
```

Comment: I couldn't find `IItemFactory` on GlassMapper.SC.100
Since i couldn't find a proper way, I cast current item to Item and then get children which return type is array and again cast it to desired list type which has performance issue for sure